# Using CSS Media Queries

Tags: html, asp.net, css, media-queries

I recently asked a question about resolution and how I can fix it in my ASP.NET web application.

With some of the answers I got I found that media queries was a good place to go.

I have set up my CSS document like the following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px) {
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
}
```

I have been developing in 1600x800 and I am wondering how do I know what I need to change the sizes of the object to. Do I have to develop the application again in a smaller browser or is there an easier way to go.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/StyleSheet.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach is basically the same as when you are writing CSS without using media queries. You still have to deal with different window sizes.

1. Drag the window edge to make the browser smaller
2. Look at how the design holds up
3. Adjust the CSS
4. Refresh the page

Comment: When I run my program and I am dragging the window how do I know what size it refers to?

Comment: In firefox browser, you have an option to see your web page in different window sizes. You can use that option "responsive design". In chrome also, when you make the window smaller, you can hover over your divs to see the actual size.

Comment: i usually do a print screen and measure it with photoshop, browser pixel rulers plugins for your browser can help too

Comment: You can use the developer tools of your browser to see what styles are being applied to any element (including ones from media queries). You can use them to look at the computed width of the html element (which will usually be the same as the browser width). There are numerous browser extensions that will tell you what the dimensions of the browser are, and more that will set it to specific dimensions.

Comment: @user3129331 try making a small C# program to capture the browser window, then you can set the size of the browser to some preset values, it's very convenient.

Comment: With the Chrome dev tools open, set to the right, the viewport height and width are shown top right of the page by default.

Comment: @AppleBud Is my code correct as I opened with chrome and then set the width of the screen to 640 and the CSS I added to the `Max-Width: 640px` isn't showing up?

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, I am using chrome which is good as it shows me the width for some reason though my CSS isn't showing when I drag the size down.

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to change the sizes of your images and fonts and also change their positions based on the different screen sizes** which you have set using the media queries. To check the different code you can resize your window and drag the border and see the effect if its working or not.

And also follow the steps which ****@Quentin**** has written it will help

Answer (score 0):

this is not exactly the right approach to follow. you should start your website with a fluid css layout grid, google it a choose one that suits you. this is an example of a fluid grid: http://onepcssgrid.mattimling.com/.

When you set up everything and designed, stretch your browser and when the design "breaks", add a media query breakpoint. deciding your breakpoints before the development is not a good idea.

a good tool to test your design may be: http://bradfrostweb.com/demo/ish/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediaqueri.es#random (enter your url in the top left box) but i usually prefer stretching my browser manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done in my website and it is working fine:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<style>
@media screen and (max-width:1900px)
{
    #content{
        margin-left:251px;
        margin-top: -197px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 420px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -30px;

    }
    #content{
        margin-left:221px;
        margin-top: -197px;
    }

    #separator
    {
        height: 50px;
    }

}
</style>
</head>
```

I checked it by resizing my chrome window and then applied width accordingly. Hope it can help you.

Comment: If you are not able to see your CSS getting applied, please check that nothing else is overriding it. Otherwise, your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Media query are the best option to solve issue related to working with different size of browser and devices. you can check your application with different tools available that shows how your application look on different device and browser.
You can check by re-sizing your browser window or you can use browser extension to check your work
**Google Chrome:**
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-web-design-tes/objclahbaimlfnbjdeobicmmlnbhamkg?hl=en
**FireFox:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View
**Opera:**
https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/responsive-web-design-tester/?display=en
**Safari:**
http://www.midwinter-dg.com/downloads_safari-extension_responsive-resize.html

To learn more about css media queries visit: http://letsdopractice.com/css-media-queries/